# Can't use DB facade in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two different controllers in the Laravel 5 default controllers folder (`app/Http/Controllers`). And I have the syntax like `DB::select(...)` in both of them. Controller #1 is working fine. Controller #2 says

> "Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in ...".

Can someone tell me why?

Controller #1 code (working fine):

```
<?php
  use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

  class Page extends Controller {
    public function foo(){
      ...
      DB::select(...);
      ...
    }
  }
?>
```

And this is Controller #2 code (not working):

```
<?php
  use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

  class User extends Controller {
    public function boo(){
      ...
      DB::select(...);
      ...
    }
  }
?>
```

And I have the only place, where I'm starting this controllers. It doesn't have "namespace", "use" or anything else.

Any ideas?

Comment: You definitely need a namespace since laravel is looking for the controller inside the App\Http\Controllers namespace. The "use DB;" to reference from the global namespace

Comment: Thanks, but "use DB" is not working anyway.
And okay, maybe namespaces is a good solution, but why my syntax works in first controller?

Comment: Have you tried `\DB::select(...);` ?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work(

Answer (score 1):

Try to include :

```
use DB;
```

Like below:

```
<?php
  use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
  use DB;

  class Page extends Controller {
    public function foo(){
      ...
      DB::select(...);
      ...
    }
  }
?>
```

For more details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database

Comment: What about the below:
`use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;`

Comment: See if in file app/config.php there is DB set up as an alias

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

in your controller